# SSO: How to login in Meteor without a password?

Tags: meteor, single-sign-on, saml, adfs

I have implemented SSO connecting ADFS with SAML in Meteor, and I can get the SAML response from ADFS successfully. Now I have a username from AD and I want to authenticate the username to login.

The only problem is that I do not know how to login in Meteor without a password.

If everyone can help I will really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of links that may be helpful:

https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/roll-your-own-authentication#!

http://robfallows.github.io/2015/12/17/writing-an-oauth-2-handler.html

Comment: Thanks for your kind help!

Comment: You're very welcome. I hope the links provide the info you need.